# UITableViewCell Size is not expanding at runtime .?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, row-height

[here is a storyboard image. i have take a dynamic tableviewcell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plku3.png) I have tried with drag and drop `UITableViewCell` and change row height from the storyboard, it cannot expanded cell height at runtime.

In `Xcode 9.0.1` and `Swift 4`, I am facing issues regarding cell height not increasing at runtime.so, pls help me for solving this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Static or Dynamic Cells?

Comment: Show your storyboard design with tablecell constraint layout and source of tableview delegate/datasource

Comment: @MartinMuldoon - dynamic cells

Comment: @Krunal- Storyboard design screen short :-https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plku3.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set automatic dimension for row height & estimated row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout.

- Assign and implement dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It's Working Now !!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**1.** Implement `UITableViewDelegate` methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 200
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**2.** Apply proper `constraints` to your `UITableViewCell` so that it can correctly calculate its own `height`. It is must for right `UITableViewCell` UI to appear. Any issue in `autolayout` might cause your cell UI to behave in an unexpected manner.